# How was one derivied from the other?

Tags: calculus, statistics, fractals, chaos-theory

In the geological paper entitled *The power–law relationship between landslide occurrence and rainfall level* by C. Li et al, a power-law cumulative probability distribution is derived. However, I don't seem to understand how exactly it was derived. Here's how it follows:

(i) A probability density function $l(R)$ is defined: $$l(R) = \frac{1}{N_{LT}}\frac{\delta N_{L}}{\delta R}$$
where $\delta N_L$ is the number of landslide occurrences at the rainfall level between $R$ and $R+\delta R$, and $N_{LT}$ is the total number of landslides in the inventory.

(ii) The probability of a landslide occurrence at the rainfall level greater than $R$ is $$L(R)=\int\limits_R^\infty l(R')dR'$$

(iii) Substituting $l(R)$ into the integral, they get $$L_{cf}(>R)=CR^{-\beta}$$

How exactly did the substitution process work? I'd appreciate if someone could explain that in steps.

Comment: Equations (4),(5), (6) of https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Li_Changjiang2/publication/251528573_The_powerlaw_relationship_between_landslide_occurrence_and_rainfall_level/links/53d8b3960cf2631430c33a1d.pdf

Comment: Yes, I know. But how did the derivation process exactly work? Can you show it step by step?